# Trying to create a tag, gettting weird message

Tags: bug

Upon trying to create a tag I get the messsage "ags do not already cover this topic" apearing in the top left hand corner of the screen in a box that is unresponsive to my mouse, the "post your question" button (as do all others) becomes unresponsive.

This happened a couple of months ago once, and I took it to be an anomalie, however it is an insurmountable barrier today, what's up?

I have a screenshot, but apparently the forum interfaces with neither dropbox nor 4shared.

Comment: While editing your post, drag the screenshot into the editing area and you can upload it so you can use it in your post.